# Can I make a online game using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm wondering in making an online easy game that runs on the browser and all I wanna know is: if I want two players to play one against the other one, online, can I make this game using HTML for the front-end and javascript to the backend rules of the gmae or do I have to use a server-side language, such as PHP for the to make one player playing against another one?

thanks

EDIT:

Today I know how vague this question is, and I'm trying to fix it.

Actually I was looking for experience with other developers and I was a complete newbie. I would like to close this topic, but I can't. I apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, but Javascript is also a server side language. I suggest looking into [node.js](https://nodejs.org/). Node.js will allow you to write all of your server-side logic in Javascript, while leaving you to write your front-end logic with whatever you see fit (read: HTML and Javascript)

[This](http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html) tutorial might be of interest to you. It uses web sockets + node.js to create a real-time multiplayer game.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, because you just mention Node.js as being server-side Javascript and then give a link

Comment: @vihan1086 what would make this response more "answer-worthy?"

Comment: Seems sufficient: vague response to a vague question

Comment: Yeah. I don't really know what else to say. If he wants to use server-side js, he'll need to use node.js. That's the short and long of it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you think creating game is simple especially online game !.
it is not simple ! and you need more than javascript. firstly you need create a framework and you can write by php. also you will need creating a database  and graphic designer.  if you can do all these you can start to write on a game engine like unity3d unreal game engine or blender. however this job will take too much time. if you create a group and work togather maybe you can create an amazing game  shortly

Comment: Thank you for the answers... I'm not saying that  creating an online game is easy, I know it takes alot of planning and time..